# PHP/Laravel magic, how does this work?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm looking at the Laravel docs, and I see this snippet:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * The layout that should be used for responses.
     */
    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

    /**
     * Show the user profile.
     */
    public function showProfile()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('user.profile');
    }

}
```

we can clearly see that $this->layout = 'layouts.master'.  However, then they define a child of the layout object (which as I understand is only a base PHP string, and does not have a field called content, via ...

`$this->layout->content = View::make('user.profile');`

1. How can a string have a field called content defined?
2. when I subclass BaseController and try to assign a value to
   $this->layout->content, why do I get the following error: "Attempt
   to assign property of non-object"?

Comment: That snippet won't work on its own. Either another class is altering `$layout` (via a setter method) or the snippet is simply wrong. Link to docs where you found this?

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/master/templates this is the docs he is referring to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not look at BaseController? It looks like they change `$this->layout`.

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/controllers/BaseController.php

```
<?php

class BaseController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Setup the layout used by the controller.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }
    }

}
```

My advice, if you use a PHP framework, don't be afraid to check its source when you don't understand why it works. There is usually much less "magic" than you think...

IMO, this seems like a bad design though, to initialize the variable as a string and then change it to be some object. Kind of just abusing the loose typing.

Comment: +1 for both "*check its source*" and "*bad design*".

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as bad design. It's very confusing at first glance but it's a very simple fix. You could just change protected $layout = 'layouts.master'; to protected $view = 'layouts.master'; and check is view is not null in setupLayout. Bad design to me would be if they had made it very hard to change this.

Comment: @mschuett, yes you can change it, and that would probably be a good design (at least better). But as it is, it's a published framework and has been designed and documented in a confusing way. But we're just arguing about the definition of "design", I think we agree that it should be different.

Comment: My main language is Java over there, this kind of thing is not even permissible. To me it seems like bad design.